# XCode error "Cannot convert value of type 'NSIndexPath' to expected element type 'Array<IndexPath>.ArrayLiteralElement' (aka 'IndexPath')"

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, compiler-errors, syntax-error

I am new to XCode and I am following an online tutorial for a shopping list program. I have this error that appears twice, "Cannot convert value of type 'NSIndexPath' to expected element type 'Array.ArrayLiteralElement' (aka 'IndexPath')".

The tutorial I'm following is here if you need it: https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-from-scratch-with-swift-building-a-shopping-list-application-2--cms-25516

If anyone is able to help me out or give me some guidance that would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

```
func controller(controller: AddItemViewController, didSaveItemWithName name: String, andPrice price: Float) {
// Create Item
let item = Item(name: name, price: price)
 
// Add Item to Items
items.append(item)
 
// Add Row to Table View
tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([NSIndexPath(forRow: (items.count - 1), inSection: 0)], withRowAnimation: .None)
// The line above is where the error occurs
// Save Items
saveItems() }
```

and the second error which is the same error message is here:

```
    // Fetch Index for Item
    if let index = items.firstIndex(of:item) {
      // Update Table View
      tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([NSIndexPath(forRow: index, inSection: 0)], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
     // The line above is where the error occurs
    }
     
    // Save Items
    saveItems()
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: This is a tutorial published in 2015, likely this is Swift 2. The current version is 5.7. Look for a more contemporary tutorial. To solve the error write `[NSIndexPath(forRow: index, inSection: 0) as IndexPath]` but you will get more errors in an Xcode version which supports at least Swift 3.